# Non suspend function is not executed after suspend function

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I have a suspend function `userRepo.updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details)` and after executing this function I want to execute `success()` function which is a call back.

but the issue is `success()` is not getting executed.

any suggestions on how to get this to work.

this sequence does not work

```
  SUCCESS -> {
                        progress.postValue(GONE)
                        userRepo.updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details) // EXECUTED
                        success() // NOT EXECUTED
                    }
```

if I change it to call success() first then save to repo, it works fine. but this is not the right way of doing it I think.

could you suggest please

```
  SUCCESS -> {
                        progress.postValue(GONE)
                        success() // EXECUTED
                        userRepo.updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details) // EXECUTED
                    }
```

Fragment call

```
viewModel.save(personalDetails) { activity?.onBackPressed() }
```

ViewModel

```
fun save(details: PersonalDetails, success: () -> Unit) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        userRepo.savePersonalDetails(details).collect {
            when (it.status) {
                LOADING -> {
                    progress.postValue(VISIBLE)
                }
                SUCCESS -> {
                    progress.postValue(GONE)
                    userRepo.updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details)
                    success() // THIS IS NOT EXECUTED
                }
                ERROR -> {
                    progress.postValue(GONE)
                    error.postValue(ErrorResult(errorCode = SNACKBAR_ID_USER_DETAILS_SAVE_FAIL))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

userRepository

```
suspend fun updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details: PersonalDetails) {
        userDao.get().collect { cachedUser ->
            val updatedCachedUser = UserDB(cachedUser.id, etc..)
            userDao.save(updatedCachedUser)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show me the function that you call?, did you already use the breakpoint to make sure the function it self was called?. cause if you dont, i think you might use nullable variable and the value will retrieved after the suspend function (userRepo.blabla()) finished, if yes. maybe you can call .invokeOnCompletion { /*your Success Function*/ success() }

Comment: you mean userRepo.updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details).invoke?
I cannot do invoke on this, not recognisable

Comment: no, wrap with coroutine like this CoroutineScope(Dispatcher.IO).launch{ you're usecase}.invokeOnComplete{}

Answer (score 0):

`success()` method isn't called because you collect `Flow` in `updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails` method:

```
userDao.get().collect {...}
```

It suspends a coroutine execution. My guess is that it is an infinite Flow, which doesn't complete until coroutine is completed. That's why `userDao.get().collect` suspends execution.

---

I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve in the `updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails` method, but it seems it doesn't update the DB. If you want to update user details in the DB, you don't need to collect `Flow`. You should have something like this:

```
suspend fun updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details: PersonalDetails) {
    userDao.update(details)
}
```

where `userDao.update(details)` is a `suspend` method, which updates DB:

```
suspend fun update(details: PersonalDetails)
```

Comment: Hello @sergey main issue was `success()` was not executed when it was written after `userRepo.updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details)`, and I want to execute `success()` once the `userRepo.updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details)` is executed. AM I WRONG IN THINKING THIS IS HOW IT SHOULD WORK?

Comment: Hello, you can't do that. Because of the reason I mentioned in my answer. The `Flow` you collect is infinite, so `updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails` will never finish execution.

Comment: okay, so I can just call `success()` first then call `userRepo.updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details)` is that acceptable to do?

Comment: I don't know, if you OK with successfully saving details calling `userRepo.savePersonalDetails` method then it is OK. Usually DB is updated in the Repository after server is successfully updated. So I can also suggest updating the DB in the `userRepo.savePersonalDetails` method.

Comment: Hello sorry I did not understand what u exactly mean by`OK` `I don't know, if you OK with successfully saving details`

Comment: It's up to you how you organize your code, but, in my opinion, what you are doing in `updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails` method is wrong. You shouldn't collect a Flow there, you need just update DB, according to your code you don't do it. Even `details` parameter, which is passed to `updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails` method is not used.

Comment: suspend fun updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails(details: PersonalDetails) {
      return userDao.get().collect { cachedUser ->
            val updatedCachedUser = UserDB(cachedUser.id, cachedUser.paymentCustomerId, 
                                           cachedUser.phoneNumber, details.firstName, 
                                           cachedUser.imageUrl, cachedUser.driverLicenseId, cachedUser.groupIds)
            userDao.save(updatedCachedUser)
        }
    }

Comment: i removed the use of details from the function just to make it simpler to look at

Comment: what do you recommend the function should be updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails

Comment: can you create a suspend method in `userDao` which returns cached user? Something like this: `suspend fun getUser(): User`. Then in `updateUserWithNewPersonalDetails` you will use next lines of code: `val cachedUser = userDao.getUser(); 
val updatedCachedUser = UserDB(cachedUser.id, etc..);
userDao.save(updatedCachedUser)`;

Comment: A Flow doesn’t have to be hot to be infinite. For example, the flows returned by Room DAOs are infinite cold flows.